# Celery 4.0.0: No such transport: django

Tags: python, django, celery

I followed the "First steps with Django" tutorial for Celery 4.0.0:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

This all works as expected. However, if I then try to change the transport from AMQP to the Django ORM by adding this to the end of `settings.py`:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'django://'
```

Then when I run the worker process (`celery -A proj worker`), I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    _main()
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 278, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 480, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 412, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 221, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 241, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 255, in run
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 99, in __init__
    self.setup_instance(**self.prepare_args(**kwargs))
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 120, in setup_instance
    self._conninfo = self.app.connection_for_read()
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 732, in connection_for_read
    return self._connection(url or self.conf.broker_read_url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 808, in _connection
    'broker_connection_timeout', connect_timeout
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 179, in __init__
    if not get_transport_cls(transport).can_parse_url:
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/__init__.py", line 81, in get_transport_cls
    _transport_cache[transport] = resolve_transport(transport)
  File "/home/ac/src/proj/.pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/__init__.py", line 62, in resolve_transport
    raise KeyError('No such transport: {0}'.format(transport))
KeyError: u'No such transport: django'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use it as a results backend, but not as a broker anymore.

The list of supported brokers is here, [on the celery project site.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/)

From the tutorial page you're following, you have the option of using the django ORM as a results backend:

> Extensions django-celery-results - Using the Django ORM/Cache as a
>   result backend
>
> The django-celery-results extension provides result backends using
>   either the Django ORM, or the Django Cache framework.
>
> The full instructions on [how to do that are located at this point on the page.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#extensions).

Short answer - Django ORM isn't a broker anymore, [it was removed in version 4.0](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#features-removed-for-lack-of-funding).

Comment: Oh, right. I was following this doc, which mentions "django" as one of the transports: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#broker-url I guess the doc is out of date?

Comment: Huh, how odd.  I think so - I've included the release notes Alasdair mentioned now, as a pointer to where that was taken out - unusual for something like that to be missed!

Comment: I created a Celery bug report and the docs have now been corrected.

Answer (score 3):

There is no a transport called `django` so you can not use `django://`. What you may use instead is `RabbitMQ` like this:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
```

Comment: remember not to use single quotation for CELERY_BROKER_URL value!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when converting to use split-settings and environs. I had left the quotes from the settings file, and environs doesn't like quotes.

Print/log the values you provide to Connect (values from settings.py). Check that you don't have extraneous symbols (quotes).